# How to use `si` format and equation format simutaneously in `tabularray`?

Tags: align, tabularray

I use `tabularray` package to make tables, in which one column is formatted as equations. When I use `si` format in this column, there is an error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.22 ^^I\end
            {talltblr}
?
```

My codes are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{talltblr}[
        caption={table},
        label={tab:table1},
        remark{Hello}={How are you today?}
        ]{
            colspec={X[c] X[c,$,si={table-format={1.5}}] X[c,$]}    
        }
        \toprule
        &{{{Column one}}}&{{{Column two}}}\\
        \midrule
            {{{One}}}&-1.2552525\dot{5}&-102.3456789\dot{3}\\
        {{{Two}}}&-66.666\dot{3}&-5.2222708\dot{3}\\
        {{{Three}}}&-3.4321&-11.12358\dot{3}\\
        {{{Four}}}&-91.01&-702.04\\
        {{{Five}}}&-1.2&-5.4067291\dot{6}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to make the columns aligned at decimal point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

By using `tabularray` package version 2022C. Changes in comparison to your MWE are marked by `% <---`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\sisetup{parse-numbers=false}   % <---
\begin{talltblr}[
        caption={table},
        label={tab:table1},
        remark{Hello}={How are you today?}
        ]{colspec={c X[c,si={table-format=-2.7}]   % <---
                     X[c,si={table-format=-3.7}]}, % <---
         row{1} = {guard}
        }
    \toprule
        &   Column one      &   Column two          \\
    \midrule
One     &  -1.2552525\dot{5}& -102.3456789\dot{3}   \\
Two     & -66.666\dot{3}    &   -5.2222708\dot{3}   \\
Three   &  -3.4321          &  -11.12358\dot{3}     \\
Four    & -91.01            & -702.04               \\
Five    &  -1.2             &   -5.4067291\dot{6}   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, why adding `\sisetup{parse-numbers=false}` can solve this problem? I check the `siunitx` file and find the setting but it didn't say this funciton.

Comment: @Y.zeng, see documentation for `siunitx` package, pages 21 -- 22.

Comment: I see it, but I don't feel it tells us this function. Maybe I can't understand it.